# Wirebox in custom tags

Tags: coldfusion, coldbox, wirebox

I have some custom tags where I do things like CreateObject().  Some of the tags are used in controllers, some in views.

I'd love to use wirebox to inject these dependencies instead.  Is there a "right way" to get a reference to the wirebox singleton from within the custom tag code?  I've looked at the caller scope, but wasn't able to find my way through it to see the wirebox instance I had in my controller's variables scope.